# Camera remains active after VideoCapture destructor is called

Tags: opencv

I've run this [sample code](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-allocation-of-the-output-data):

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) return -1;

    Mat frame, edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine, but after the application closes, the camera remains active. I know this because the flash led stays on until I kill the HPMediaSmartWebcam.exe process.

How do I close the camera after I've finished using `VideoCapture`?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the way the camera driver is implemented. Probably nothing to do with OpenCV. You may try a hackish approach and kill that process programatically before exiting your app. But make sure it can be started correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs...[here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) the camera will be deinitializd automatically in the class destructor...the destructor calls a virtual function `cv::VideoCapture.release(`)...run the camera for a fixed number of frames and then see whether the LED of the webcam goes off or not..

```
int frames = 0;

while(frames!=1000)
{
  //do frame capture from webcam and image processing...
  ++frames;
}
```

Comment: didn't work. I also think that the opencv buffer shouldn't hold the camera active even if it still holds frames.

Comment: I ran your code with opencv 2.4.3...I have a Dell Integrated Webcam...your code is working fine with the webcam LED turning off with and without a number of frames constraint...try adding the line cap.release() after the while loop...

Comment: already tried that, no luck... I guess it's something with the HP driver